# DNS resolving from Cloudfunctions in VPC network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-functions

I am deploying a Cloudfunction with VPC network as follows:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy my-function
      --trigger-http
      --region europe-west1
      --memory 128MB
      --runtime nodejs16
      --entry-point entrypoint
      --allow-unauthenticated
      # needed to access compute instances
      # https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/connectors/list
      --vpc-connector cloud-function-connector
      # vpc connector should be used only to access private network
      --egress-settings private-ranges-only
```

Now, if my Cloudfunction uses IP address of compute resources, I can easily access them. However when I use their hostnames, the DNS are not resolved which ends up with:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND my-compute-resource
```

What do I need to do to be able to use DNS for my compute instances?

Comment: Which hostnames - public or private? **my-compute-resource** is a hostname. You must use the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN). https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#view_instance_dns_name

Comment: `my-compute-resource` is a name of the instance. From other instances I can easily ping directly `ping my-compute-instance`. Thanks to you I found out that I can use `my-compute-instance.c.my-project.internal` - I guess that is the best I can get?

Comment: I sometimes use /etc/hosts and store hostnames and IP addresses. Then I can use any name I want (short or FQDN).

Comment: @ Vojtěch  Have you tried as @JohnHanley  suggested? If yes, Can you post the procedure which you have followed as an answer.

Comment: Hi, I have just used `my-compute-instance.c.my-project.internal` instead of `my-compute-instance` and thats how it works.

Comment: @Vojtěch please post your solution as an answer and accept it so that it would be helpful for other community members for reference.

Comment: @JohnHanley if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a resource via a host name, you must use the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN). Only using the host portion will fail.

A Compute Engine VM has the following FQDN format:

```
VM_NAME.ZONE.c.PROJECT_ID.internal
```

If you only specify the VM_NAME, for which ZONE and PROJECT_ID should the request resolve to? That answer also determines which internal DNS server should be queried for the answer.

To prevent that ambiguity, Google Cloud DNS requires FQDN.

[Internal DNS names and Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#view_instance_dns_name)